# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

The following line of code gives me the above error in Keras. model is a Graph model in Keras.

```
score, acc = model.evaluate({
    'input1': X_test1,
    'input2': X_test2,
    'output':Y_test}, batch_size=450)
```

but when I change it to the following, it runs fine.

```
predictions = model.predict({
    'input1': X_test1,
    'input2': X_test2}, batch_size=450)['output']
```

The Y_test here is a `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>` of `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`. A one-hot encoded vector.

Sample `Y_test`:

```
[[1.,0.,0.],[1.,0.,0.],[0.,0.,1.]]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you can see here :

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py

The evaluate method returns only test loss (or losses). So assigning result of this method to a pair results in error.

Comment: Thank you, for pointing that out. It seemed to work fine for the Sequential model, but now I am guessing that it returns two metrics.

Comment: Actually, it returns the test loss and any metrics requested. Assigning the result to a pair `score, acc` would have worked had the accuracy metric been requested from the model fitting

Comment: This is an quite old answer. `Keras` changed a lot since this time.

Answer (score 0):

Using keras 1.0 I was able to get the score print out but I would receive this error when I tried to get the score and accuracy.

I downgraded my keras to 0.3.3, and ran the exact same code. I was able to get score and accuracy doing this.